# Hyperlink problem

Tags: hypertarget

I want to refer to the Theorem and corollary at different places with the same number. But it's not working, any idea of an alternative to this issue. Thanking you in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}    
Theorem \hypertarget{3.5.1} {\hyperlink{3.5.1}{3.5.1}}
\pagebreak

Please refer Theorem {\hyperlink{3.5.1}{3.5.1}}

Corollary \hypertarget{3.5.1} {\hyperlink{3.5.1}{3.5.1}}
\pagebreak
Please refer Corollary {\hyperlink{3.5.1}{3.5.1}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why did you ask this exact question one more time?

Comment: I am satisfied with your previous answer sir but it was posted earlier with using a different syntax. @daleif Thank you!